# Using document.cookie in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, cookies, gatsby

I need to be able to set and access cookies in my Gatsby project, and I was able to get something solid setup using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/react-hooks-usecookie-hook-26ac06ff36b0). I'm building a hook that sets a cookie, and utilizing it throughout the site. This is what the helper looks like when it's all said and done.

**use-cookie.ts**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const getItem = (key) =>
  document.cookie.split('; ').reduce((total, currentCookie) => {
    const item = currentCookie.split('=');
    const storedKey = item[0];
    const storedValue = item[1];

    return key === storedKey ? decodeURIComponent(storedValue) : total;
  }, '');

const setItem = (key, value, numberOfDays) => {
  const now = new Date();

  // set the time to be now + numberOfDays
  now.setTime(now.getTime() + numberOfDays * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
  document.cookie = `${key}=${value}; expires=${now.toUTCString()}; path=/`;
};

/**
 *
 * @param {String} key The key to store our data to
 * @param {String} defaultValue The default value to return in case the cookie doesn't exist
 */

export const useCookie = (key, defaultValue) => {
  const getCookie = () => getItem(key) || defaultValue;
  const [cookie, setCookie] = useState(getCookie());

  const updateCookie = (value, numberOfDays) => {
    setCookie(value);
    setItem(key, value, numberOfDays);
  };

  return [cookie, updateCookie];
};
```

I'm calling the hook into a component like so:

**DealerList.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode, useEffect } from 'react';

import { Container } from 'containers/container/Container';
import { Section } from 'containers/section/Section';
import { Link } from 'components/link/Link';

import s from './DealerList.scss';
import { useCookie } from 'hooks/use-cookie';

interface DealerListProps {
  fetchedData: ReactNode;
}

let cookie;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    cookie = useCookie();
  }, []);


export const DealerList = ({ fetchedData }: DealerListProps) => {
  const dealerInfo = fetchedData;
  if (!dealerInfo) return null;
  
  const [cookie, updateCookie] = useCookie('one-day-location', 'sacramento-ca');

  return (
    <>
      <Section>
        <Container>
          <div className={s.list}>
            {dealerInfo.map((dealer: any) => (
              <div className={s.dealer} key={dealer.id}>
                <div className={s.dealer__info}>
                  <h3 className={s.name}>
                    {dealer.company.name}
                  </h3>
                  <span className={s.address}>{dealer.address.street}</span>
                  <span className={s.city}>{dealer.address.city} {dealer.address.zip}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={s.dealer__contact}>
                  <span className={s.email}>{dealer.email}</span>
                  <span className={s.phone}>{dealer.phone}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={s.dealer__select}>
                  <Link
                    to="/"
                    className={s.button}
                    onClick={() => {
                      updateCookie(dealer.phone, 10);
                    }}
                  >
                    Select Location
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Container>
      </Section>
    </>
  );
};
```

It works well on `gatsby develop` and I'm able to access the value of the cookie and change the contact information that's displayed accordingly. However, when I try and build, or push to Netlify, I'm getting this error.

`WebpackError: ReferenceError: document is not defined`

I know this has something to do with `document.cookie` on lines 4 and 17, but I'm struggling trying to figure out how to fix it. Any suggestions? I'm imported `useEffect`, and from my research that has something to do with it, but what can I do to get it working properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit more research, and I found [this simple hook](https://gist.github.com/lwkchan/2dfe69061ff4f4cc6606f48f36c07e6d), replaced the code in `use-cookie.ts` with this, made a few modifications to it (included below), installed `universal-cookie` and it seems to work perfectly. Here's the new code:

**use-cookie.ts**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

export const useCookie = (key: string, value: string, options: any) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  const [cookie, setCookie] = useState(() => {
    if (cookies.get(key)) {
      return cookies.get(key);
    }
    cookies.set(key, value, options);
  });

  const updateCookie = (value: string, options: any) => {
    setCookie(value);
    removeItem(value);
    cookies.set(key, value, options);
  };

  const removeItem = (key: any) => {
    cookies.remove(key);
  };

  return [cookie, updateCookie, removeItem];
};
```

If anyone has a better way to do this though, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Gatsby's Debugging HTML Builds documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/):

> Some of your code references “browser globals” like `window` or
> `document`. If this is your problem you should see an error above like
> “`window` is not defined”. To fix this, find the offending code and
> either a) check before calling the code if `window` is defined so the
> code doesn’t run while Gatsby is building (see code sample below) or
> b) if the code is in the render function of a React.js component, move
> that code into a componentDidMount lifecycle or into a `useEffect` hook,
> which ensures the code doesn’t run unless it’s in the browser.

So, without breaking the rule of hooks, calling a hook inside another hook, causing a nested infinite loop. You need to ensure the `document` creation before calling it. Simply by adding a checking condition:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const getItem = (key) => {
  if (typeof document !== undefined) {
    document.cookie.split(`; `).reduce((total, currentCookie) => {
      const item = currentCookie.split(`=`);
      const storedKey = item[0];
      const storedValue = item[1];

      return key === storedKey ? decodeURIComponent(storedValue) : total;
    }, ``);
  }
};

const setItem = (key, value, numberOfDays) => {
  const now = new Date();

  // set the time to be now + numberOfDays
  now.setTime(now.getTime() + numberOfDays * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
  if (typeof document !== undefined) {
    document.cookie = `${key}=${value}; expires=${now.toUTCString()}; path=/`;
  }
};

/**
 *
 * @param {String} key The key to store our data to
 * @param {String} defaultValue The default value to return in case the cookie doesn't exist
 */

export const useCookie = (key, defaultValue) => {
  const getCookie = () => getItem(key) || defaultValue;
  const [cookie, setCookie] = useState(getCookie());

  const updateCookie = (value, numberOfDays) => {
    setCookie(value);
    setItem(key, value, numberOfDays);
  };

  return [cookie, updateCookie];
};
```

Since you might be calling `useCookie` custom hook in a component or page where the `document` doesn't exist yet, I would double-check by using the same condition or using a `useEffect` with empty dependencies (`[]`, now it won't break the rule of hooks):

```
const Index = props => {
  let cookie;

  // both works
  if (typeof document !== undefined) {
    cookie = useCookie();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    cookie = useCookie();
  }, []);

  return <Layout>
    <Seo title="Home" />
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
  </Layout>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this such a helpful start. I changed up `use-cookie.ts` using this code, but it's only displaying the initial cookie `sacramento-ca` now. I updated my question to include more code.

Comment: Thought I had an answer, but it didn't seem to work like I need it to.

Comment: What happens with `universal-cookie`? What's the issue?

Comment: I'm trying to set an initial cookie in my header that can be changed, but I can't get that done.

Comment: Also, integrating your first solution here, I'm getting an 'Invalid Hook call' error.

Comment: Figured it out. I had placed my `useState` hook inside the `DealerList` component in the wrong place.